# Django CMS breadcrumb

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm trying to create an automatically generated breadcrumb using Django CMS's menu system. So far I have created an AttachMenu to generate the underlying menu structure, and this works great for generating the breadcrumb as well.

The problem though, is that I don't want this part of the menu structure to be rendered as a submenu of the main menu, which I render using `{% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}`. I can't set the first `100` to `0` as other submenus should be rendered.

I saw the Modifier class, which takes the `breadcrumb` argument which sounds like what I want. However, it shouldn't be used to create a whole submenu.

The only solution I see at the moment is to use both an AttachMenu and a Modifier, and then use the modifier to cut off the whole submenu from the menu structure whenever the current call is **not** a breadcrumb, but this sounds like a very hacky way to achieve this.

I'm wondering if anyone has a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
{% load menu_tags %}
<nav class="my-breadcrumbs">
    <ol itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    {% show_breadcrumb %}
    </ol>
</div>
```

Note that pages that have the "Menu" option disabled, will not be listed in the breadcrumb.

Comment: Why not? The possible to make them show if not in menu?

Comment: @BasharAl-Abdulhadi, yes. See `{% show_breadcrumb 0` under [Menus and navigation > show_breadcrumb](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/navigation.html#show-breadcrumb).